# undefined symbol: _ZNK10tensorflow*

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, tensorflow, shared-libraries, bazel

Following [this](http://hugh-obrien.com/blog/2017/02/12/tensorflow-for-unity.html) guide on running TensorFlow within unity. I've looked around but can't seen to find anything that helps. I'm placing the libTFModel.so file inside "project_name/Assets/Plugins/libTFModel.so" directory and within a C# script I'm importing the shared object using 
`private const string LIBRARY_NAME = "TFModel";
[DllImport(LIBRARY_NAME)]` which finds the file but then outputs  `undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow19kColocationAttrNameE` and hence won't run. I've seen [this](https://jacobgil.github.io/deeplearning/tensorflow-cpp) post which mentions that the *.so file generated by bazel contains strictly TensorFlow symbols, so i'm wondering if the
`bazel build :libTFModel.so` command should have any special flags?

Comment: Are you building within a clone of the TensorFlow repository? If so, try building with a `tf_cc_binary` rule instead of `cc_binary`? You'll need to add `load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_cc_binary")` to the top of your BUILD file.

Comment: I am and I've tried that, even then it gives the same undefined symbol error.

Comment: Is the symbol in libtensorflow_framework.so?

Comment: How would I check? And if so should I be placing libtensorflow_framework.so within unity3d?

Comment: `nm -g /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so | grep ColocationAttr` suggests that the symbol is there on my machine. So yes, it looks like the issue is libTFModel.so not finding libtensorflow_framework.so. `objdump -a -x libTFModel.so | grep PATH` will tell you where it's looking (and I'd also check `ldd libTFModel.so` to make sure it's looking for `libtensorflow_framework.so`).